# How does the $\lambda$ invariant propagate with extra ramification?

Tags: nt.number-theory, iwasawa-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}^{cyc}$ denote the cyclotomic $\mathbb{Z}_p$ extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $\Lambda$ denote the corresponding Iwasawa algebra. Let $p$ be a prime. Let $S$ denote a finite set of primes not containing $p$ and $X_S$ the maximal abelian $p$ power extension of $\mathbb{Q}^{cyc}$ which is unramified at primes $l\notin S$. Let $X=X_{\Phi}$ for the empty set. It is known that $X$ and $X_S$ are both torsion $\Lambda$-modules with $\mu(X)=\mu(X_S)$.

How does $\lambda(X)$ compare with $\lambda(X_S)$?